# Are there genuine/updated instructions on how to make Notepad++ "understand" (syntax highlighting) a custom library/framework of mine?

Tags: notepad++, php, syntax-highlighting

*Please note: I have in the past several years many times searched online for this, read the Notepad++ documentation and experimented heavily with Notepad++. I could not ever make it do this in spite of seemingly doing what it wanted me to do. Please only respond if you know that this works; I have more than likely seen various guides and webpages that you might link me to.*

I have made a PHP framework/library. I am able to create any kind of custom file format that Notepad++ wants for me to get its syntax highlighting to "understand" my system. I'm not talking about the annoying "auto-complete" stuff which I always have to turn off the first thing I do after installing Notepad++. I'm talking about things such as:

```
$variable = nope;
```

"nope" is not a valid constant in PHP, but I may have defined that constant to be an alias to "true" (without the quotes). Currently, Notepad++ cannot possibly know about this because I now have a vanilla Notepad++ installation. I'm trying to figure out how to create a "syntax helper file" of some sort which Notepad++ will load upon program start and then cause my "nope" to be recognized as a constant/special keyword and thus get the same syntax highlighting treatment as would a "false" or "true" (without the quotes).

I want to make extremely clear that I do *not* want to "define my own language". Whenever I try that feature, all existing syntax highlighting is erased and it starts over from zero. I absolutely don't want that. I'm simply trying to have the default PHP syntax highlighting, but also make it "understand"/know about my own list of custom functions/constants/whatever.

No matter what I've tried in the past, Notepad++ seems to just ignore whatever files I edit or expand upon, or add. Somebody even claimed to me that Notepad++ ignores all those files and loads this data from somewhere else. I hope that was just temporarily while they were restructuring the application years ago or something. Basically, nothing is documented in any meaningful manner, and "just fiddling about" never results in anything.

I'm seriously starting to wonder if this is even possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Boy, you sure have a lot of restrictions on how to respond to your question, don't you ;)

ANYWAY:

I'm hearing that you *don't* want "Language > User Defined", you simply want to extend PHP syntax highlighting.  Cool :)

I don't think you can extend the built-in syntax highlighting to accommodate PHP "nope".  Specifically:

> https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15983/php-additional-syntax-highlighting/2
>
> Q: Is it at all possible to add to php syntax highlighting, i.e. some
> combination of keywordClass and styleID that will work, or am I
> waisting time ?
>
> A: What categories there are available for a given language are
> defined by that language’s lexer; unfortunately, you cannot add new
> categories. (Well, like you saw, you can add anything you like to
> stylers.xml… but if the php lexer isn’t programmed to match words in
> that category, and to pass on the category to scintilla to mark it
> with a particular style, nothing will happen.)
>
> So, with the builtin lexer, I don’t think you’re going to be able to
> add a separate style/category of keywords, sorry.
>
> You might be able to come up with a UDL to highlight the words as you
> desire (but UDL highlighting often falls short in areas that the
> custom lexers excel in, so you may have to give up something in order
> to get the two different categories of keywords).

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "restrictions". I know from experience that a lot of people just make a search and link to the first thing they see, and that's always something which doesn't work. Trying to avoid this, obviously. As for your answer, I believe I've read that many times, but it seems to me that this is just not possible because Notepad++ is fundamentally broken. Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: It seems very strange to me that it wouldn't allow this, though. When you say that I "don't want" a user-defined language, that's because it clears all the existing syntax highlighting, and my framework/library is not a different language from PHP.